# in app purchase need to upload binary

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

For in app purchase in ios is there any way to test the integration without submitting the application for review? Every tutorial I read asked me to upload a binary for apple to review .

Thanks

Comment: Test the integration of the in-app purchase? I don't think it is possible as Apple needs to have the purchase setup so that you can use it.

Comment: You only need to create an app on itunesconnect and add an in app purchase for the app... You should be able to test it after it processes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a sandbox, see [Testing a Store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Now it is possible to create a `.storekit` configuration file and it will be used to "fetch" your products. Go to `File` -> `New` -> `File` -> `StoreKit Configuration File`. Open it and in lower-left corner tap on the `+` button and add the product you set up in AppStore Connect:

[image: Adding a new product]

---

Then, when filling information make sure your `Product ID` matches the one from AppStore Connect:

[image: Filling data]

---

The last thing is to let your scheme know about this configuration. Tap on your schema in upper-left corner and go to `Edit scheme...`. Under `Options` tab you will find this screen. Here you select your config file:

[image: Enabling configuration]